# Is there a way using Javascript/jQuery to fire an event on an elements deletion?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp, jquery-events

Say I have a jsp page that consists of a singular div with a button inside the div, as well as some jQuery creating an event handler for that buttons click. This jsp page is then inserted into another jsp page inside of a separate div using ajax. See code below for an example:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <input id="rand" type="button" value="random" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery("#rand").on("click",function(){
                console.log("I clicked on random!");
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    <input id="changeBtn" type="button" value="change" />
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery("#changeBtn").on("click",function(){
            jQuery("#child").html("Hello World!!");
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is that whenever the elements/html/text within the "child" div is removed/replaced, so say on `changeBtn` click event we set the html for "child" to be "Hello World", an event would be fired that would clean up the events that have been registered for elements within the "child" div. So I want the click event handler for "rand" button to be removed whenever the text within that div is removed. Similar to a window.unload event but for a div whenever it gets "unloaded".

I appreciate any help with this issue, if it even is an issue.

Comment: Not really. There are DOM mutation events/observers, but they are very "implementation dependent". The clean approach is simply to handle such case manually when/before you replace the contents. (There really isn't a [modern] memory leak issue, as the DOM will cull the event handlers itself.)

Comment: Ya, that is what I was afraid of. I was attempting to clean up my pages by doing something similar to what I mentioned in the question but after countless hours of googling and this question I am convinced that it is not possible. Thank you!